# If I can not call a method in the onCreate() where do I call it? Android/Java

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error: "Android System services not available to Activities before onCreate()"

Where else would I put my method call if I need it fired when the activity starts?

```
public class DownloadPosters extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_posters);

        //I have a class that is storing two id's from the previouse activity.
        String eventid = PosterSessionData.getEventId();
        String postercatid = PosterSessionData.getPosterCatId();

        //This method is part of this class (should I even be extending ActionBarActivity here?
        new CallFileLocations().execute(null, eventid, postercatid);
    }
```

The CallFileLocations() fires off an AsyncTask that gets file locations from my server. Inside the onPostExecute() I loop the results and fire an outside class that manages the download.

inside onPostExecute():

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = posters.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = obj.getString("poster_title");
                    String line = "Poster: "+title+ " Rev: "+obj.getString("rev");
                    String link = obj.getString("poster_filepath");
                    String cleanLink = link.replace("\\", "");
                    myTextView.append(line + cleanLink + " : Go Download");
                    String fileName = obj.getString("poster_filename");
                    myTextView.append("\n");
    ***************************************************************                   
                    //when I added this I recieved the error.
                    DownloadHandler file = new DownloadHandler("example.com/"+cleanLink+"/"+fileName+".pdf", title, fileName);
```

This is the DownloadHandler which exists as its own class file

```
public class DownloadHandler extends Activity {
            DownloadManager downloadManager;
            private String fileName;
            private long myDownloadReference;
            //private BroadcastReceiver receiverDownloadComplete;
            //private BroadcastReceiver receiverNotificationClicked;

        public DownloadHandler(String s, String title, String f) throws Exception {
            fileName = f+".pdf";
            downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setTitle(title);
            request.setDescription("Now Downloading");
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadHandler.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
            myDownloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        }

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED);

        BroadcastReceiver receiverNotificationClicked = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                String extraId = DownloadManager.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_CLICK_DOWNLOAD_IDS;
                long[] references = intent.getLongArrayExtra(extraId);
                for (long reference : references){
                    if (reference == myDownloadReference){
                        //do something with the download file
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);

        BroadcastReceiver receiverDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                long reference = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

                if (myDownloadReference == reference){
                    //do something with the download file
                    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    query.setFilterById(reference);
                    Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    //get the status of the download
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                    int fileNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);
                    String savedFilePath = cursor.getString(fileNameIndex);

                    //get the reason - more detail on the status
                    int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
                    int reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason);

                    switch (status){
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                            //START Activity TO display the download image
                            Toast.makeText(DownloadHandler.this, "File: "+fileName+" has been downloaded.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                            Toast.makeText(DownloadHandler.this, "FAILED:" + reason, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                            Toast.makeText(DownloadHandler.this, "PAUSED:" + reason, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                            Toast.makeText(DownloadHandler.this, "PENDING:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                            Toast.makeText(DownloadHandler.this, "RUNNING:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };


        @Override
        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            unregisterReceiver(receiverDownloadComplete);
            unregisterReceiver(receiverNotificationClicked);
        }
        @Override
        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            // Register the BroadcastReceiver
            registerReceiver(receiverDownloadComplete, filter);
            registerReceiver(receiverNotificationClicked, filter);
        }


    }
```

Comment: I don't think you are showing the part which is causing the issue

Comment: I added the lines where I loop the return JSON Object and instantiate the DownloadHandler. This is what is causing the problem

Comment: One thing, I don't see why that is extending `Activity`. Also, I don't see where you are trying to call or start that activity. You need to post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: @codeMagic... I extended activity because the editor complained that getSystemService() method could not be resolved. I will run and copy the stacktrace

Comment: Extending the activity wouldn't be the fix. The fix would be to pass your Activities `Cotnext` and use that with `getSystemService()`

Comment: so in my constructor i would (Activity activity,...) and then in my call i would new DownloadHandler(this, "http://...)??

Comment: Let me try to clear it up in an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, from comments we learned that you extend `Activity` in the class which gets the data because you are trying to use `getSystemService()` and this method needs a `Context`...this is the wrong fix.

Remove `extends Activity` and add a `Context` pram to your constructor, create a member variable such as `Context mContext` and pass the `Activity Context` to it from your actual `Activity`.

```
public DownloadHandler(String s, String title, String f, Context c) throws Exception {
    mContext = c;
```

and use it here

```
downloadManager = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

now pass the appropriate `Context`

```
 DownloadHandler file = new DownloadHandler("http://mysite/"+cleanLink+"/"+fileName+".pdf", title, fileName, DownloadPosters.this);
```

You still haven't posted the stacktrace but I suspect the issue is in the activity which shouldn't be an activity and `onCreate()` is never called because you aren't instantiating the `Activity` correctly.

My answer gets you part of the way there but you need to take out the UI stuff for now until you learn how to handle that outside of an `Activity`. Use logs instead of `Toasts` in that case.

Comment: Ok, I am going to correct it now.. do you mind removing the real http address. I accidently pasted that into the question and have changed it to example... Thank you for your help. brb

Comment: Done, didn't pay any attention. Unfortunately, it will still be in the revision history.

Comment: Ok, doing this cleared the error that this question asked about. Thank you. However from what I can tell the download never happened. Could it be that I am just creating the class instance and not really understanding how to fire the DownloadManager

Comment: That is very likely. If you can't figure it out, post a new question after you clean all of this up and make sure to include the most relevant code and explain what is/isn't happening.

Answer (score 1):

Loading data in `onCreate()` isn't a good idea even from conceptual point of view. `onCreate()` is called only once in activity lifecycle, whereas pause/resume may happen multiple times and you MAY need to update data each time.

I'd call it in `onResume()` method (check activity documentation for details about lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Also check information about loaders which are created exactly for pourpose of data loading: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Also, loading the data *may not* be what the OP but it also *may* be what he needs. That's entirely up to his structure.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I could certainly call the data onResume however if that activity is resumed the data would not have changed. I don't know if that makes a difference. I dont think that storing it in a class is best either. As soon as I get my downloader figured out I will learn how to sqlite

Comment: @codeMagic IMHO problem MAY lay in basics of activity understanding/implementation, thus actual solution may be rewriting it from beginning

Comment: @silversunhunter you don't need sqlite for your task but you can reuse Loaders (AsyncTaskLoader) in your design. They were prepared exactly for your needs - i.e. asynchronously loading data thus looking at them may give good inputs to your design

Comment: After giving an answer and digging into it more, that is a fair point and I have retracted my downvote.

Comment: @Daimon, you are right, I am just now learning about how an activity is created and managed. Its a lot to digest coming form a stateless web app development background.